# How to trigger a workflow in one file based on the output of another workflow result

Tags: build, yaml, workflow, github-actions

I have one file build.yml which have jobs, steps for a react app deployment. I have another workflow file issue.yml which is responsible for creating an issue if any steps gets failed in build.yml.

I would like to trigger workflow file issue.yml only when workflow file build.yml have an issue. I know, I can achieve it, if I created another step in workflow file build.yml to create an issue and use condition if failure().

Just wanted to check if anyone have idea to achieve it by using 2 different workflow files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a the `workflow_run` trigger in your `issue.yml` workflow:

If you inform to start it only when the informed workflow is `completed` (with success or failure) you will be able to do what you want doing something like this:

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["<build workflow name>"]
    types: [completed]

jobs:
  on-success:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
      ...
  on-failure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'failure' }}
    steps:
      ...
```

You can find more information about this trigger on the [Events that trigger workflows documenation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run).

Comment: This only works on the default branch which might not be what OP is looking for.