# Is it possible to call another workflow file from another workflow file's condition statement?

Tags: yaml, github-actions, workflow

I referred many answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68243295/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-in-one-file-based-on-the-output-of-another-workflow-re) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750603/github-actions-trigger-another-action-after-one-action-is-completed), but none of them were satisfactory since they call another workflow directly.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Build"]
    types:
      - completed
```

Above workflow triggers when workflow is completed/succeeded.

So far, My code can handle errors better, so it'll always (I hope it to be) succeed.

Let's say:

- `workflow_1.yml`
- `workflow_2.yml`

I want to call `workflow_2.yml` from `workflow_1.yml`. This is simple and can be done with:

```yaml
- name: Call another workflow
  uses: ./.github/workflows/workflow_2.yml
```

but, can I call `workflow_2.yml` like this?

```yaml
jobs:
  update_fork:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Forked Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # some other steps that makes condition to be true
      - name: Call another workflow
        run: |
          # some other code
          if [ $condition == "true" ]; then
            # call workflow_2.yml
          fi
```

**Edit_1:**
I added if statement as another step to the above code:

```yaml
- if: ${{ steps.fetch.outputs.build_app == 'true' }}
  uses: ./.github/workflows/android_build.yml
```

I'm pretty much sure by now that this will not work and hence it kept throwing this below error:

```
Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/wftest/wftest/.github/workflows/android_build.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

This is because, I need to call it from another job i.e., it is illegal to call another workflow within a step as far as I remember.

Comment: Why not simply add an `if` for the step itself and mention the workflow in `uses`? Under `run` it's a shell now. The workflow should be meaningless there unless there's another runner there accepting jobs which I'm sure is not the case here. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: I'm trying automate stuffs a bit. `workflow_1.yml` fetches updates from upstream. Only if update exists, it'll fetch commits. Else, prints "no commits to sync". Since it fetches commits, I want to call the workflow_2.yml that builds the app after syncing with upstream

Comment: There could be multiple ways to achieve this. You can simply set an env var i.e. `GITHUB_ENV` and check that in the next step with `if`. The next step will only proceed if that env var is set. Another alternative would be to set the output i.e. `GITHUB_OUTPUT` instead and use that in the `if` condition.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178201/outputs-for-github-actions-on-windows-hosted-runner

Comment: Ok, so, on successful fetch, I'm supposed to store a variable, say 1, into `env` and check whether env has a one or not in a different if step. If yes, call `workflow_2.yml`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, As this is part of the same job, using an env var seems to be a straightforward solution. See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable. You may use the output as well. See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter. IMO, using the output would be more expressive.

Comment: Ah, I started this, I got confused, stopped and asked here! I think this will be my answer... I'm stopping for now since I need to study for tomorrow's (monday) exam. I'm thinking of using output so that I can see what's happening over there.

Comment: Yes, that should solve this. Good luck!

Comment: I was able to implement the thing, but builds are failing just because it cannot find the file. `Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/wftest/wftest/.github/workflows/android_build.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?`

Comment: Please update your question with all the details. From that message, it does look like the checkout is missing or it's a different branch with different content.

Comment: I updated my question some more details. Please do check it out.

Comment: Please include your complete workflow which is reproducible in isolation.

Comment: Updated the code again

Comment: According to docs (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow), "**You call a reusable workflow by using the `uses` keyword. Unlike when you are using actions within a workflow, you call reusable workflows directly within a job, and not from within job steps.**".

Comment: You can configure this second workflow which should run when the first one finishes. See [workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) for more details.

Comment: FYI, I've been roaming on the pages that you shared now since morning today.. with no success so far. I'm aware that I need to call it via uses immediately after creating another job and that's I've mentioned  in my question. I currently have no idea about how to implement them under condition statement.

Comment: For your use case, you don't need a reusable workflow. You need one workflow that syncs your repo (that you already have shared) and another one that runs on its completion (one that builds it). With `workflow_run`, you can mention the condition in your second workflow that it should run on the successful completion of the first one. Even with a reusable workflow, you'll have to mention that somehow and that's why I mention `workflow_run` in my previous comment but that would add redundancy of creating "envelop" workflow which is not needed at all. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've already played a bit with `workflow_run`. But the thing is, I don't want to trigger `build_workflow.yml` everytime runs since the first workflow doesn't fail. What happens if I don't add a condition is that, the build would be triggered everytime, the `wf1.yml` is triggered. I only want it to trigger only if upstream has got some commits to be merged.. My thinking currently is that, read output of `wf1.yml` in `wf2.yml` and only run if that variable has value. IDK how to achieve that as of now

Comment: Right. I believe that's doable by setting output parameters for jobs. See this example: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-outputs-from-a-reusable-workflow. You need to slightly change your current config. Move the second workflow from the step and put it under another job e.g. `build`, add a `needs: update_fork` section, and then use the output of the previous job i.e. `if: ${{ needs.update_fork.outputs.build_app }}`. I think that's pretty much it. That should do it.

Comment: Here's a very similar example: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci-win-share-output-bw-jobs.yml but it's without a reusable workflow.

Comment: please elaborate this a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in and out the documentation for about 11 hours by trying and testing few other methods, I learnt that, currently, there's no way to call another `workflow` within `steps` and it is not possible to share values between `workflow.yml` files.

I solved this by following my own traditional method which is described below.

#### Logic

I cannot call a workflow based on condition. However, that doesn't stop me from raising an error.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75192054/12320089) answer of mine describes what I was trying to do in the first place.
Adding command: `exit 1` in the `else` block in the `foo.yml` file immediately stops the execution by throwing an `Error`. However, if the below is added in the `bar.yml`, it doesn't stop the execution of it on failure.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
  workflow: ["Foo"]
    types: [completed]
```

A simple method to get around this is to call the workflow i.e., call `bar.yml` from `foo.yml`'s new job as shown below.

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    # some code 
    if [this]; then
      echo "Hi"
    else
      exit 1
    fi
  job2:
    needs: job1
    uses: ./.github/workflows/bar.yml
```

Since `job2` is now dependent on `job1`, `bar.yml` isn't called for execution until `foo.yml` is succeeded which is possible only `if` statement is executed.